# keys not in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to whether an argument is a dictionary, if its length is 4 and if it has any key whose name its not in this tuple: `('posicao','vida','forca','exercito')`.

If there is *any* key whose name is *not* in that tuple, the function should return `False`.  But instead it continues until `return verifica_pos(arg)` and I can't figure out why that happens:

```
def eh_unidade(arg):
    nom_chaves = ('posicao','vida','forca','exercito')
    if isinstance(arg, dict) and len(arg) == 4:
            for key in arg:
                if key in nom_chaves:
                    return verifica_pos(arg)
                else:
                    return False
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Could you add code that shows an example of running this function, and what the result you expect for a couple of different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use sets to clean up the (broken) logic of the program:

```
NOM_CHAVES = {'posicao', 'vida', 'forca', 'exercito'}

def eh_unidade(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, dict):
        keys = arg.keys()

        if len(keys) == 4 and set(keys) <= NOM_CHAVES:
                    return verifica_pos(arg)

    return False
```

Or, we could use an `all` and `map` combination:

```
NOM_CHAVES = ('posicao', 'vida', 'forca', 'exercito')

def eh_unidade(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, dict):
        keys = arg.keys()

        if len(keys) == 4 and all(map(lambda key: key in NOM_CHAVES, keys)):
                    return verifica_pos(arg)

    return False
```

Or we could rearrange your original code and add a couple of negations:

```
NOM_CHAVES = ('posicao', 'vida', 'forca', 'exercito')

def eh_unidade(arg):
    if not (isinstance(arg, dict) and len(arg) == 4):
        return False

    for key in arg:
        if key not in NOM_CHAVES:
            return False

    return verifica_pos(arg)
```

Comment: ok its almost right the only problem is if i change the order of any key it gives false instead of giving true

Comment: @MartimCorreia, I tested my above examples and key order doesn't make any difference, nor would I expect it to.  Provide more code examples in your original question.

Comment: ok, forget it, it actually works i tried the 2nd and it worked thanks